# Static IP address for custom SPFx App and SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, api, sharepoint-framework

I have a custom web part that I'm building using SharePoint Framework to go on my SharePoint Online tenant. The application will be hitting a third-party API to fetch data.

The complication is that the third-party API provider needs me to provide them with an IP address, as they restrict access to their API via IP.

The official Microsoft documentation on [Microsoft365 IP Ranges](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/enterprise/urls-and-ip-address-ranges?view=o365-worldwide#sharepoint-online-and-onedrive-for-business) does not provide one IP range, but ranges (which makes perfect sense since we have users all over the world), which I'm guessing will not fly with the API provider.

Curious if anyone has any ideas on approaches. The only thing I can think of is to have a random VM running in Azure/AWS with a static IP that fetches data from the third-party service and then exposes it to my SPFx web part (feels a bit clunky).

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would turn it back on the provider and ask how they handle cloud integrations given the static IP requirement. Seems like a problem if they are not cloud-native out of the box.

Aside from that you could use an Azure API gateway and put a static IP on that. A lot cheaper than a VM. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-features